# Good download manager for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, download-manager

I'm looking for a download manager module for Drupal. Ideally, it would give the same sort of power that the Sourceforge manager or the Drupal theme download manager gives. That is:

- Multiple download objects, with descriptions
- Each type has multiple versions available
- Nicely delimited on the page
- Unstable, Supported, and Unsupported markers would be nice, but not necessary.

Ease of administration would be nice, but I can handle an arcane upload system if that's what's available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal's [Project](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) module (it also has a few other module add-ons) might well be the thing you are looking for. Some details about it (from its project page):

> Projects are generally assumed to represent software that has source code, releases, and so on. The Project module provides the primary "project" content type(s) and the ability to classify and browse projects. The included Project release sub-module enables managing downloads of different versions of the software represented by the projects. These modules provide the project and release management tools for Drupal.org.

Answer (score 0):

Project works for me, since I'm fine with using Drupal 5.